# How does following code works in Batch Scripting(.bat) file?

Tags: batch-file

How does following code works in Batch Scripting(.bat) file?

```
:modifyString what with in toReturn
    SET "__in=%~3"
    SET "__in=!__in:%~1=%~2!"
    IF NOT "%~4" == "" (
        SET %~4=%__in%
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO %__in%
    )
```

Comment: What do you use the code for? Does it not behave as you expect? Did you do any research on your own? Hints: [`call`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) (explains `%~1`, etc.); [`set`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) (explains sub-string syntax); [`if`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) (explains `if` query); type each command into a command prompt window, followed by `/?` and _ENTER_, to get the respective help text...

Answer (score 1):

Assign the contents of the third parameter, stripped of quotes to the variable.

replace any occurrence of the first parameter in that string with the second parameter (both stripped of quotes)

If the fourth parameter is not missing, set the variablename which is the fourth parameter to the result of the previous operation. If it is not not missing then display the result of the previous operation.

(yes - I know about the double negative - but that's how it's coded)